# Why is double brace required to initialize std::array of structs

Tags: c++

In C++17, why does this way of initializing std::array not work?

```
#include <array>
#include <string_view>

class myClass {

private:  

 struct myStruct {
        const std::string_view a;
        const int b;
        const int c;
    };

    static inline constexpr std::array<myStruct, 2> myArray = {{"", 0, 0},{"", 0, 0}};
};
```

I thought this style was covered by the changes in CWG 1270. However, the only way I found to make it work is to do:

```
   static inline constexpr std::array<myStruct, 2> myArray = {{{"", 0, 0},{"", 0, 0}}};
```

or

```
   static inline constexpr std::array<myStruct, 2> myArray = {myStruct{"", 0, 0},myStruct{"", 0, 0}};
```

Comment: Recommend adding the error you get to the question as well so I can be sure (or as sure as we can be with different compilers emitting different error messages) we're both looking at the same problem.

Comment: And Sam just went in the same direction i was headed. He just simplified the problem further. [I stopped at the struct and the array](https://godbolt.org/z/3f57z37rY)

Answer (score 1):

Let's use a much simpler example to work this out:

```
std::array<int, 3> arr{{1,2,3}};
```

We start by reviewing [how `std::array` is defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). It has the

> same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array T[N] as its only
> non-static data member.

So, in other words, this `std::array` is an object with a single "non-static data member" that's a C-style array. Based on that, we can work out that:

- the outermost set of braces server initialize the `std::array` itself.
- the innermost set of braces initialize this unnamed data member.

In other words, this is exactly the same thing as:

```
struct my_array {

    int a[3];
};

my_array arr{{1,2,3}};
```

And that's why a double set of outer braces is always used to initialize an instance of a `std::array`.

Comment: While I do understand your explanation, your example can be further simplified by using only single braces:

std::array<int, 3> arr{1,2,3};

So, my question was about why I cannot do that with a struct type?